# In a Gmail add-on is there a reliable way to work with an individually selected message within the conversation?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

We're looking into building a Gmail add-on to replace our [Gmail contextual gadget](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets) and trying to work out a  way to provide equivalent features.

Because a contextual gadget is displayed underneath each message in a conversation we used this to display contact details and allow storing a copy of specific messages within a conversation.

For Gmail add-ons the add-on is passed a `messsageId` in the event object and sometimes the add-on will refresh with a new `messageId` when clicking or expanding messages in the conversation. However, this does not appear to be consistent and there doesn't appear a clearly explicit action to select a "current" message in a conversation that the add-on should act upon.

In [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/actions#action_event_objects) `messageId` is described as as *the "message ID of the thread open in the Gmail UI* so it's not clear if this is meant to refer to a specific message or the overall conversation.

We also took a look at the Android Gmail app and the add-ons only appear to be accessible when scrolling down to the end of the conversation, so similarly I'm unsure if an add-on can be triggered for specific messages in the mobile UI?

We looked at the [Trello add-on](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/trello_for_gmail/710372432947) as an example. This allows creating a Trello card using the first few words from an email message as the description for the card and we noted that the description would *sometimes* update to reflect a different message in the conversation when clicking the headings or body of messages in the conversation, but again not consistently.

Can anyone from the Gmail add-ons team advise if what we're seeing are just some quirks that are being worked on, or if we're approaching the add-on design with the wrong model in mind and shouldn't be developing around the concept of individual messages in the conversation?

Comment: Yeah, at the moment there doesn't seem to be a way to reliably work with an individually selected message. A user can accidentally switch the context of the addon by tapping or clicking around.

Comment: Thanks @akshay - have you been making a Gmail add-on yourself? Feel free to get in touch if you'd like to exchange any tips :) (contact details are in my SO profile.)